# Passing data in Laravel between a controller and a mailable

Tags: laravel, email

I can't seem to get data transferred after I submit a create form of a model record to a mailable. I think I'm right on most of it, but I'm stuck at passing the data through the gap between a controller and my mailable.

I have a shipment controller with the following function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate(request(), [

        'pro_number' => 'required',
        'shipment_origin' => 'required'
        /*'piecesNumber' => 'required' (had to remove for now, but must review)*/

    ]);

    $user_id = Auth::id();

    $input = $request->all();

    //Save Initial Shipment Data
    $shipment = new Shipment();
    $shipment->pro_number = request('pro_number');
    $shipment->shipment_origin = request('shipment_origin');
    $shipment->date = request('date');
    $shipment->due_date = request('due_date');
    $shipment->tractor_id = request('tractor_id');
    $shipment->trailer_id = request('trailer_id');
    $shipment->driver_id = request('driver_id');
    $shipment->notes = request('notes');
    $shipment->shipper_no = request('shipper_no');
    $shipment->ship_to = request('ship_to');
    $shipment->ship_from = request('ship_from');
    $shipment->bill_to = request('bill_to');
    $shipment->bill_type = request('bill_type');
    $shipment->load_date = request('load_date');
    $shipment->shipment_status = 0;
    $shipment->created_by = $user_id;

    $shipment->save();

    //Save Shipment Details

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->shipment_details['piecesNumber']); $i++) {

        Shipment_Detail::create([
            'shipment_id' => $shipment->id,
            'pieces_number' => $request->shipment_details['piecesNumber'][$i],
            'pieces_type' => $request->shipment_details['piecesType'][$i],
            'rate_type' => $request->shipment_details['rateType'][$i],
            'charge' => $request->shipment_details['charge'][$i],
            'weight' => $request->shipment_details['weight'][$i],
            'hazmat' => $request->shipment_details['hazmat'][$i],
            'description' => $request->shipment_details['description'][$i] ]);
    }
    $user = Auth::user()->email;

    Mail::to($user)->send(new newFreightBill($shipment));

  Session::flash('success_message','Freight Bill Successfully Created'); //<--FLASH MESSAGE

    //Return to Register
  return redirect('/shipments/i/'.$shipment->url_string);

}
```

Now as you can see there is a line near the bottom "Mail::to($user)->send(new newFreightBill($shipment));", what I would like to be doing is moving the copying the data from the submitted $shipment to the mailable

My newFreightBill mailable:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

use App\Shipment;

class newFreightBill extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $shipment;

    public function __construct(Shipment $shipment)
    {
        $shipment = $this->shipment;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('MYEMAIL')
                    ->view('emails.shipments.created')->with(['shipment', $this->shipment]);
    }
}
```

and my mail template (which I do receive in my tests):

```
<div>
    Pro Number: {{ $shipment['pro_number'] }}
</div>
```

As you can see the template is VERY simple to say the least. I get in my emails to me the following:

> Pro Number:

but absolutely nothing else, no actual number. SO I know the issue is passing the data from the form submit to the mailable variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using properties on your Mail class such as `public $shipment`, you shouldn't use `with()` method. The properties on your class are available on your view without the need of using `with`.

And then you should do this: Pro Number: `{{ $shipment->pro_number }}`

Oh yes, and this: `$shipment = $this->shipment;` is backwards, it should be `$this->shipment = $shipment;`.

Comment: If I make the suggestions you stated, I get the following error: Trying to get property of non-object in reference to {{ $shipment->pro_number }}

Comment: @Matthew I updated my answer, check the last part again :)

Comment: Yes it did! Thank you again so much for the help!